# Why won't `Async.SwitchToContext` return?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to scrape some websites that need to run their JavaScript before the document has all the data I'm interested in. I'm trying to open a `WebBrowser` and wait for the document to load, but I can't get the data when I try to switch back to the thread the `WebBrowser` is on. Trying to run it without switching back to the thread gives casting errors. = (

What's stopping the `async` from switching threads? How do I fix this problem?

#### Script

```
open System
open System.Windows.Forms
open System.Threading

let step a = do printfn "%A" a

let downloadWebSite (address : Uri) (cont : HtmlDocument -> 'a) =
    let browser = new WebBrowser()
    let ctx = SynchronizationContext.Current
    browser.DocumentCompleted.Add (fun _ ->
        printfn "Document Loaded" )

    async {
        do step 1
        do browser.Navigate(address)
        do step 2
        let! _ = Async.AwaitEvent browser.DocumentCompleted
        do step 3
        do! Async.SwitchToContext ctx
        do step 4
        return cont browser.Document }

let test = 
    downloadWebSite (Uri "http://www.google.com") Some
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

---

#### Output

```
> 
1
2
Document Loaded
3
# It just hangs here. I have to manually interrupt fsi.
- Interrupt
>
4
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that `RunSynchronously` blocks the thread that you are trying to use to run the rest of the asynchronous computation using `Async.SwitchToContext ctx`.

When using F# Interactive, there is one main thread which runs in the F# Interactive and handles the user interactions. This is the thread that can use Windows Forms controls, so you correctly create `WebBrowser` outside of `async`. The waiting for `DocumentCompleted` happens on a thread pool thread (which runs the async workflow), but when you try to switch back to the main thread, it is already blocked by `Async.RunSynchronously`.

You can avoid blocking the thread by running a loop that calls `Application.DoEvents`  to process events on the main thread (which will also allow it to run the rest of your async). Your `downloadWebSite` stays the same, but now you wait using:

```
let test = 
    downloadWebSite (Uri "http://www.google.com") Some
    |> Async.Ignore
    |> Async.StartAsTask

while not test.IsCompleted do
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
  System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents()
```

This is a bit of a hack - and there might be a better way of structuring this if you do not really need to wait for the result (e.g. just return a task and wait before running the next command), but this should do the trick.

Comment: I've toyed around with this but now I'm back to the old error when trying to access `test.Result`: `System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.`

Comment: @jks612 Yeah, I got that too - I'm not sure what this means, but it's happening inside `WebBrowser`, so it looks like something browser related, rather than thread related. Does that work as expected if you run things without any threads?

Comment: it works fine if I manually wait for the event. I was using the async to wait for the event to fire. I'm going to look at using tasks instead now.